# can't connect from android device to computer with socket

Tags: android, python, sockets, tcp, wifi

I'm using my computer as server and android as client, both on the same wifi.
I'm using standard tcp socket code which can be found here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication but with changed ip

Comment: please show your android code

Comment: im running the client code from the link on android

Comment: did you run that python code in android?

Comment: yep, the exact same

Comment: AFAIK python does not run on android

Comment: well it can, just download a python env

Comment: please show your python setup in android, then

Comment: its the standard python app on android, found on playstore. i have opend it put my code in and the press run

Comment: That will not work of course. You will have a very specific exception to begin with. That ide will display the exceptions i suppose?